# understanding c++ class and function calls

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to understand this example we did in class but having some trouble...

For a class Time, an instance of this class is made up of hrs, mins secs

So

```
Time labStart(10,30,0);
Time labEnd (12,20,0);

 (labEnd-labStart).printTime() //I'm not concerned with the printTime function

const Time Time::operator - (const Time& t2) const {

    int borrow=0;
    int s=secs-t2.secs;

    if (s<0) {
     s+=60;
     borrow=1;
    }

    int m=mins-t2.mins2-borrow;
     if (m<0) {
     m+=60;
     borrow=1;
    }
    else 
      borrow=0;

    int h= hrs-t2.hrs-borrow;
     if (h<0) {
     h+=24;

     Time tmp=Time(h,m,s);
     return tmp;
}
```

So if we are passing both labEnd and labStart, and I was told (labEnd-labStart) ~ labEnd.operator-(labStart)

I dont understand how and where labEnd's variables are considered? In the function above only one parameter of Time is passed in, labStart, so the t2.mins t2.sec accounts for labStarts mins and secs,(30 mins and 0 sec respectively) however where is labEnd's variables (12,20,0)?? (instance variables hours, mins, secs)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `this` is a pointer to `&labEnd`. The bare `secs`, `mins`, and `hrs` mentions have an implicit `this->` in front of them. If you write out the `this->`'s explicitly the three variable declarations become:

```
int s = this->secs - t2.secs;
int m = this->mins - t2.mins - borrow;
int h = this->hrs  - t2.hrs  - borrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labEnd - labStart
```

is equivalent to:

```
labEnd.operator -(labStart)
```

So `labEnd` is `this` in the member function, and its member variables can be accessed as if they were ordinary variables.